# How to make jTextArea Transparent background

Tags: java

I want to make a transparent background jTextArea.
I try to setBackground(new color(0,0,0,0));
jTextField is Working, jTextArea didn't working.

like this code.

```
// Not working.. Just remains gray.
    jScrollPane1.setOpaque(false);
    jScrollPane1.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
    jTextArea1.setOpaque(false);
    jTextArea1.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));

    // Working.. As it wants to be transparent.
    jTextField1.setOpaque(false);
    jTextField1.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
```

[image]

How can I jTextArea transparent background?

Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `JScrollPane` is a composed component, it controls/contains a `JViewport` which is the component that does the drawings. See API:

> A common operation to want to do is to set the background color that
>   will be used if the main viewport view is smaller than the viewport,
>   or is not opaque. This can be accomplished by setting the background
>   color of the viewport, via scrollPane.getViewport().setBackground().
>   The reason for setting the color of the viewport and not the
>   scrollpane is that by default JViewport is opaque which, among other
>   things, means it will completely fill in its background using its
>   background color. Therefore when JScrollPane draws its background the
>   viewport will usually draw over it.

So you should change the opaque and color properties of the `JViewport`as well. You can access it with `jScrollPane1.getViewport()`.

Comment: I knew why that does not work, thanks to you. Problem was solved.

Answer (score 5):

The following worked for me.

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
textArea.setOpaque(false);
textArea.setBackground(new Color(red, green, blue, alpha));

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
scrollPane.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
scrollPane.setOpaque(false);
```

Comment: ah, this is enough..... setOpaque(false) is quite enough for me. thank @josemr.

Answer (score 0):

This is example include 50% transparent

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
textArea.setOpaque(false);

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea) {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        try {
            Composite composite = ((Graphics2D)g).getComposite();

            ((Graphics2D)g).setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.5f));
            g.setColor(getBackground());
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

            ((Graphics2D)g).setComposite(composite);
            paintChildren(g);
        }
        catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
        }
    }       
};

scrollPane.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
scrollPane.setOpaque(false);
```

**edit** sorry for the bug. This is work.